# Reading JSON using fetch in typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was looking for this stuff on the internet and I found that:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch. I am relativey new to typescript so there are a few things that confuse me.

First what's the difference between:

```
fetch('data.json')
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
   //data = myJson;
});
```

and

```
fetch('data.json')
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.json()));
    //data = response.json();
})
```

The first works well but the second piece of code does't. Why is that? As far as I know `fetch` retuns the promise of `JSON` and in `.then`, `response.json()` holds the actual `JSON` object. But the second version doesn't work (I get `undefined` in console).

My second question is how to get out the value of `myJson`. I tried doing that with global variable but it didn't work (I get `undefined` in console):

```
var data
fetch('data.json')
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(myJson) {
   //console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
   data = myJson;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason we need to use `response.json()` is because `Fetch` returns an HTTP response. To extract the JSON body content from the response, we use `json()` method.

The reason you are getting `undefined` is because of `async` nature of javascript. Try using `async` and `await` to solve this issue or print the data inside of the `then()` not outside of it.

Comment: But why the first piece of code works and second doesn't. I am using  response.json() in both, but the second has an extra .then? And also how can I synchronize this operation? Await needs to be used in async function and I would like for the code below to run synchronously and I couldn't find anything like join() in C++ to do that.

Comment: So, In the first one Fetch returns an HTTP response with a lot of overhead like headers and body. Ideally you only need to body section so you use `response.json()` which resolves a promise and gives you only the needed results. In the second one you are trying to `stringify` and print a Promise which when being printed may be  in pending state. Apparently in JS to make things sync we use Promises or `Async Await`. Copy all the code below the `.then()` to inside of `.then()` and it will act synchronously.